# IBM MobileFirst Sending JSON Body from iOS SDK to Java Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

Using IBM Mobile First PlatForm Version 7.1 I am trying to call a Java Adapter from iOS Application using following code.

```
    [[WLResourceRequest requestWithURL:url method:WLHttpMethodPost] sendWithJSON:@{@"one":@"two"} completionHandler:^(WLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"%@",response);
    NSLog(@"%@",error);

    }];
```

Java Method on adapter side looks as following.

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public String hello(JSONObject body){
    return body.toString();
}
```

But I get Following error in response

> 2016-04-20 11:31:15.520 mbs-call[15092:3787968] Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: unsupported media type (415)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL: http:/0.0.0.0:10080/mbs-api/adapters/basicadpt/users } { status code: 415, headers {
>       Connection = Close;
>       "Content-Language" = "en-US";
>       "Content-Length" = 0;
>       Date = "Wed, 20 Apr 2016 02:31:15 GMT";
>       "X-Powered-By" = "Servlet/3.0";
>   } }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://0.0.0.0:10080/mbs-api/adapters/basicadpt/users, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unsupported media type (415)}

And it seems that in iOS SDK it adds header `application/x-www-url-form-urlencoded` in request when any method is called.

**I have following 2 questions.**

1. How to pass JSON Body to Java adapter?
2. Behaviour of `sendWithJSON` is different on iOS and Android. On Android it seems to add `application/json` header when we call adapter. Is that a bug or part of behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug. I think that using `sendWithJSON` should automatically assume that the content type is `application/json`.

I suggest that you open a support request (PMR) so that they can improve the experience.

In the meantime, I found an easy workaround:

```
[request addHeaderValue:@"application/json" forName:@"Content-Type"]
```

Or in Swift:

```
request.addHeaderValue("application/json", forName: "Content-Type")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with the cordova version of an application.

```
var userIDTag = 'some_string';  
var subTag = [userIDTag]; //<- this worked
var subTag = userIDTag; //<- this failed with the above error
var subTag = '[\'' + some_string + '\']'; //<- this also failed with the above error
```

The below is what I ended up doing for a Cordova app.

```
function subscribeByTag(userIDTag) {
    var subTag = [userIDTag];
    console.log("subTag: " + subTag);
    WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken("push.mobileclient").then(
        MFPPush.subscribe(
            subTag,
            function(subTag) {
                navigator.notification.alert("Subscribed successfully");
            },
            function(failureResponse){
                navigator.notification.alert("Failed to subscribe");
                console.log("Failedtosubscribe:" + JSON.stringify(failureResponse));
            }
        )
    );
}
```